# How do I use list comprehension to remove values that are within 10 of each other, keeping only 1?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension, python-2.x

I have a list like the following:

```
[[454.0, 82], [451.0, 82], [449.5, 82], [448.0, 82], [316.0, 82], [313.0, 82], [311.5, 82]]
```

I want to use list comprehension to remove items that are within 10 of each other.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
>>> lst = [item for item in lst for i in range(len(lst)) if item[i+1] - item[i] > 10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

The above list comprehension looks like it should work, but it results in an `IndexError`.

Desired output:

```
[[454.0, 82], [316.0, 82]]
```

What I mean by *within 10 of each other* is if the absolute value of `a` - `b` is greater than 10.

**I want this to return 1 value for all of the values that are within 10 of each other.**

Comment: Can you  more clearly explain what you mean by items that are *within 10 of each other* ?

Comment: Why do you think that python will find the Euclidean norm for you?

Comment: @aj8uppal a and b being what, exactly?

Comment: It seems the suggested output should be blank because for any element in the example there is another element within distance 10.0

Comment: `[454.0, 82]` appears to be "within 10" of `[451.0, 82]`. Shouldn't it be removed?

Comment: What's so great about list comprehensions that you'd want one instead of code that works?

Comment: The problem with your expected output is that the first element is an edge case because it doesn't meet the condition that it has a difference of 10 from the next element's value. I have an answer, but you will have to edit the question to clarify that edge case.

Comment: What should it return for `10, 20, 30`? `10, 30` or `20`?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. But Is this what you want? `reduce(lambda a,b: a + [b] if abs(b[0] - a[-1][0]) > 10 else a, lst, [lst[0]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go past the end here -- i+1 is outside the original list for the last entry:

```
for i in range(len(lst)) if item[i+1]
```

Perhaps it works if you simply do `len(lst) - 1`

Other way is to not use list comprehension but a normal for and check for more conditions there.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
a=[[454.0, 82], [451.0, 82], [449.5, 82], [448.0, 82], [316.0, 82], [313.0, 82], [311.5, 82]]
result=[]
diff=10
num=0
for i in a:
    if abs(i[0]-num)<10:
        if i[0]>num:
            result.append(i)
            num=i[0]
    else:
        result.append(i)
        num=i[0]


print result
```

output:[[454.0, 82], [316.0, 82]]

Comment: Yes. but how do I make this a one-liner? (list comprehension)